# How to sort a 2D numpy array lexicographically by one column?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, lexicographic

how to sort numpy 2D array with 2 elements: 
For example I have:

```
[['0.6435256766173603' 'some text']
 ['0.013180497307149886' 'some text2']
 ['0.017696632827641112' 'some text3']]  
I need:
[['0.6435256766173603' 'some text']
 ['0.017696632827641112' 'some text3']
 ['0.013180497307149886' 'some text2']]
```

I tried np.argsort, np.sort, but it doesn't work! 
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You have a `numpy.ndarray` with *strings*? You should probably just use normal Python lists...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want your array lexsorted by the 0th column, `np.argsort` is what you want.

```
out = x[np.argsort(x[:, 0])[::-1]]
print(out)
```

---

```
array([['0.6435256766173603', 'some text'],
       ['0.017696632827641112', 'some text3'],
       ['0.013180497307149886', 'some text2']],
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = np.array([['0.6435256766173603', 'some text'],
              ['0.013180497307149886', 'some text2'],
              ['0.017696632827641112', 'some text3']])

a[a[:, 0].argsort()[::-1]]
```

should yield

```
array([['0.6435256766173603', 'some text'],
       ['0.017696632827641112', 'some text3'],
       ['0.013180497307149886', 'some text2']],
      dtype='|S20')
```

Breaking it down:

```
# the first column of `a`
a[:, 0]  

# sorted indices of the first column, ascending order
a[:, 0].argsort()  # [1, 2, 0]

# sorted indices of the first column, descending order
a[:, 0].argsort()[::-1]  # [0, 2, 1]

# sort `a` according to the sorted indices from the last step
a[a[:, 0].argsort()[::-1]]
```